# Making county-level shapefile from set of points at 30 x30 km spacing using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data, geoprocessing, r

I have a data set in csv form, like:

```
latitude, longitude, value
-45, 45, 10
....
```

I would like to calculate county level means from these data, using either ArcGIS or R+grass.

I have the ArcGIS USA Counties layer, but I have not been able to successfully complete a spatial join.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## A workflow used to generate county level shape file with mean(z) in each county from an xyz data table in ArcGIS

*note* this is based on @MLowry's suggestion, adding almost step-by-step instructions.

---

### Open ArcCatalog

1. create new personal geodatabase (e.g. foo.mdb)
2. file -> new -> personal geodatabase
3. add data

   - right click on map.csv -> export to geodatabase (single) -> foo.mdb
   - right click on counties.lyr -> export to geodatabase (single) -> foo.mdb
4. create featureclass (.shp files) from  xy table

   - open foo.mdb
   - right click map.csv table --> create featureclass from xytable
   - input fields x = lon, y = lat, z = yield
   - coordinate system of input coordinates import -> from counties.lyr (or, equivalently,  -> geographic .. -> world -> wgs_1984 -> open -> ok)
5. import feature classes to geodatabase (multiple)

   - select shp files created in prev. step -> add -> okay

### Open ArcMap

1. Add data

   - select foo.mdb -> CTL + select tables -> open
2. Spatial Join

   - ArcToolbox -> Analysis Tools -> Overlay -> Spatial Join ->
   - Target Features: counties.lyr
   - Join Features: xyz table map
   - Output Feature Class: filename_spatialjoin
   - Join Operation: JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE
   - Match Option: Closest
   - Field Map of Join Features: remove unwanted fields (only STATE_FIPS, CNTY_FIPS, z-values required
   - Search Radius: 30km
   - click `OK`
   - Z value = yield; select 'mean' (or alternative statistic)

Comment: @David Thanks for the detailed answer ... will have to check it out.

Comment: @Abe feel free to edit when you do. I have made it CW

Comment: @David In this circumstance, IDW will produce incorrect results for the zonal statistics: see the discussion following @scw's reply.

Comment: @whuber. Thanks for pointing that out. By the time I was finished I had forgotten that the original point was to do a spatial join on the points with counties; fixed.

Comment: @David Thanks.  But now I'm confused.  First, where in this workflow do you actually create a "raster layer," as your title announces?  Second, how is it that *three* layers are produced?  The CSV file merely represents a set of points (x,y), each with a single numerical attribute (z).

Comment: @whuber aha. I forgot to change the title to match the question; Also, I was fiddling with three tables of different resolution but the OP only mentioned one so I will fix again. Thanks again for the keen eye.

Comment: +1 Kudos for the effort to help the OP achieve a spatial join.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you could convert the .csv to an event theme, then export to .shp, then do a spatial join with the new .shp into the county layer, and BOOM, you're good to go for the calculations.

Answer (score 6):

A general approach is to convert your regularly spaced point data into a raster (XYZ to raster in Arc*; [v.in.xyz](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass65/manuals/html65_user/r.in.xyz.html) in GRASS) then perform a zonal statistics operator to aggregate the values of the cells within each county and calculate statistics (mean is one of the standard statistics calculated). To perform the statistics, use [Zonal Statistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Zonal_Statistics/009z000000w7000000/) in Arc*, or [v.rast.stats](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass65/manuals/html65_user/v.rast.stats.html) in GRASS.

If you needed to do more advanced statistics, you could do the analysis in R with `raster` and `sp` but its a little more tricky.

Comment: Good idea, but unless the point arrays are oriented correctly with the coordinates, resampling will occur in the conversion to a raster and you'll be at the mercy of the resampling algorithm: the averages will likely be off by a tiny bit no matter what.

Comment: Right, if the cell size is set to coarsely resampling may occur. As an approximation, you should be able to set the cell size to half the minimum distance between any two points and avoid this issue. This approach does have the downside of having to handle resampling, but I've found it much better then the number of points is large (tens of thousands or more).

Comment: @scw Resampling occurs no matter what the cellsize is (unless the data are already perfectly aligned with the grid).  When using a finer cellsize, you will likely get *worse* answers, because most of the grid values are interpolated between the originals.  Unless you are using nearest-neighbor interpolation, this causes the extreme values to be under-represented.  The mean will only slightly be affected; other statistics, such as the standard deviation, can be more heavily affected.

Comment: @whuber I think I see where our misunderstanding is coming from -- I'm not advocating converting the data into a continuous surface, only placing the point values (when they exist) into a regular raster grid. So the vast majority of the grid will remain NULL, with only occasional values at cell locations coincident with point locations.

Comment: @scw Ah, very good!  Thank you for the clarification.  You are in effect doing the grid-based equivalent of the spatial join recommended by @MLowry.

Comment: Isn't converting to rasters adding some unnecessary overhead and over complicating the problem? The data is vector and the analysis can be done more quickly and accurately as vectors.

Comment: @Sean That's a fair criticism, although whether using rasters is a "complication" may be a matter of preference and experience.  The mitigating factor in this case is the OP's (vague) statement that a vector solution (the spatial join) has not worked.  A more potent criticism of a raster solution is that Arc* does not effectively aggregate multiple points falling into the same cell, which can cause errors when some of the data are silently dropped during the CSV to raster conversion.