# Exporting county level data in *.shp file to text (csv) file in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, csv, file-formats

I have a shape file created as per the answer to my [previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/10610/3218), which includes county level means for each county in the US.

How can I now export this data in a .csv file, e.g. with just the state, county, and county_mean fields?

Comment: The answer is in the second hit when you Google "ArcGIS  export .csv".

Comment: @whuber yes, but the answer (as restated below) is to first export to .dbf, open the dbf with Excel, and then export to .csv OR to use an third-party tool. The first workflow is frustrating, the second is satisfactory.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ArcGIS will export a .dbf to .txt. You can then rename it to .csv. First turn off the fields you do not want exported under Properties, Fields. Right-click the table, data, export. Select the browse folder button, change the "save to type" to .txt.

---

Step-by-step instructions to follow comment by @Brandon (ArcMap 10.1)

- Right Click on .shp in TOC
- Open Attribute table
- Click 'table options' tab in upper right of Table
- Export
- Next to Output table: click yellow folder

  - change "save as type" to "Text File"
  - change extension to ".csv"

Comment: +1. To be clear... the export options from the table view are different than when right clicking in the TOC. For a shapefile, you would first need to open the table view and export using the menu there. Additionally, you can add the .csv extensions directly from the dialog and eliminate the need to rename after.

Answer (score 4):

According to the ArcGIS [forums](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1149&t=160514):

### Either:

- Right Click on .shp file
- Data -> Export
- Open .dbf file with favourite spreadsheet program (Excel and Gnumeric work)
- Export as .csv

### Or

- Download the tool for ArcToolbox written by [Dan Patterson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/681/dan-patterson) [here](http://forums.esri.com/Attachments/14482.zip)